# Spring custom Converter not applying - no matching editors or conversion

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I use Spring MVC 4.3.3, Data 1.10.4, Thymeleaf 3, Hibernate 4.3.5, Oracle 10g, JBoss Wildfly.

I have custom objects, converter not kicking in when controller tries to save it; bindingResult has error.

```
@Entity
public class Cat{
  private CatType catType;
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/create", params={"save"})
public String save(final Cat cat,...){ //error here
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "cat/create";
    }
    ... 
}
```

My Thymeleaf form trying to submit is

```
<li>
    <span>Type</span>
    <select id=catType name="catType" th:field="*{catType}">
        <option
            th:each="catType: ${allCatTypes}"
            th:value="${catType.getId()}"
            th:text="${catType.getName()}">
                Category type
            </option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Relevant error is

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'cat' on field 'catType': rejected value [100]; codes [typeMismatch.cat.catType,typeMismatch.catType,typeMismatch.ae.tbits.atn.aiwacore.common.model.CatType,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [cat.catType,catType]; arguments []; default message [catType]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ae.tbits.atn.aiwacore.common.model.CatType] for property 'catType'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ae.tbits.atn.aiwacore.common.model.CatType] for property 'catType': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

So I create a converter (also tried formatter).

Thymeleaf config

```
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(catTypeConverter());
    super.addFormatters(registry);
    logger.info("Added formatters");
  }

  @Bean
  public CatTypeConverter catTypeConverter(){
    return new CatTypeConverter();
  }
}
```

And my converter class

```
public class CatTypeConverter implements Converter<String, CatType> {
  public CatTypeConverter(){
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public CatType convert(String source){
    ...
  }
```

If I put a breakpoint in my ThymeleafConfig.addFormatters(), I can see my converter being added to converters collection, it is present. But later when I break in controller save method, my converter is missing from the converters collection. So mysteriously my converter is getting cleared, hence the error I think.

I researched all over SO, couldn't get it to work.

Among others, I followed this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-conversion-service

Comment: Although this is unsolved, I tried PropertyEditor and was able to get it to work. Would love to get to the bottom of this so if anyone has suggestions then please do enlighten.